# How do I refresh the data (and the corresponding view) inside a fragment from another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Have tried searching and tested all possibilities on StackOverflow but I'm still stuck, so many apologies if this seems like a duplicate!

**Here's an overview on what I'm trying to achieve:**

I have a user profile. It is made up of UserProfileActivity and UserProfileFragment, where the view and data projections are handled in the fragment. A user ID (objectId) is also being passed to display the profile of the respective user.

On this user profile, you can click to a list of the user's followers (made up of ListFollowerActivity and ListFollowerFragment). On this list of followers, clicking on an individual person leads to UserProfileActivity again, this time with a different user ID.

**What's happening currently:**

The code I currently use to load the UserProfileActivity (with a new user ID) from the ListFollowerFragment is;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(parent, UserProfileActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(C.bundleKey.objectId, objectId);  // objectId = user ID!
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've done a out.println on the object ID from the reload intent in ListFollowerFragment and it correctly prints the correct user ID. (The ID of the user which is tapped on.)

But in reality, the app reloads the same user profile (which is the former user ID and not the new one) again.

How do I get the UserProfileFragment to refresh the data (and the view) to reflect the correct user?

*Some observations:*
It seems that UserProfileActivity is simply 'restoring' from its previous state (previous user ID) from second and subsequent loads. (Any out.println() I do from onCreate() in UserProfileActivity and onCreateView() in UserProfileFragment is not readable from the second load onwards, but reads correctly on the first!)

I've also attempted finish() on UserProfileActivity when navigating to ListFollowerActivity, and all subsequent loads of UserProfileActivity worked with the correct user Ids, presumably because the activity is killed and restarted. But this also means the user is unable to back-navigate. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I found the following:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.UserProfileActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled.NoActionBar"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

I changed the launchMode to '**singleTop**' and all navigation began working as desired.

'**standard**' launch mode works too, although this will constantly create new instances of UserProfileActivity (assuming we traverse deeper into viewing profile A --> viewing A's follower list --> tap to profile B --> viewing B's follower list --> tap to profile C, I believe this is not very good for performance).

'**singleTop**' on the other hand, lets you reuse the current instance as long as it exists above the current activity in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the `objectID` with `getExtra()` from your `UserProfileFragment` . Something like this.

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("objectId"))
            object_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("objectId");
```

Comment: The new objectId in the intent is always retrieved in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in UserProfileActivity. But somehow on the second and subsequent UserProfileActivity loads, the code in UserProfileFragment is not reached. (Did out.printlns to verify this!) Any idea? (:

Comment: So you mean `objectId` is retrieved correctly on `onCreate` for the first time ?

Comment: I think you should try at `onCreateView` and leave `onCreate` alone. please let me know the result.

Comment: The objectId is always retrieved correctly on onCreate (in UserProfileActivity) on the first time. But on subsequent loads of the user profile, it simply restores from its previous state (previous user ID) instead of taking into account the new objectId and reloading the view. (To counter this, I actually attempted finish() on UserProfileActivity when navigating to ListFollowerActivity ... which made all subsequent UserProfileActivity load the way it should! But this also means, the user cannot do a back navigation. :/)

Comment: Will try that and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, didn't work! :( onCreateView() in UserProfileFragment was not reached on second and subsequent user profile loads.